# Can you use an Ethereum key for Web Authentication (WebAuthn)

Tags: encryption, ethereum, public-key-encryption, webauthn

Is the format that is used for Ethereum key (ECDSA whatever) compatible with the W3C Web Auth standard.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that WebAuthN generates a new set of PKI credentials for each relying party, so the standard does not natively support authentication with a preloaded key (Ethereum key) across relying parties.